# Open link in new tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to open a link to an external page in a new tab but if the link hasn't http or https is opening in salesforce like

> www.salesforce.com/somepage

This is my code in a Lightning component

```
<a href="www.somepage.com" target="_blank">Some Page </a>
```

Also, I tried

```
<ui:outputURL value="www.somepage.com" label="Some page"/>
```

Do you know how I can open the page without adding http/https?